# A migration path to Math Overflow?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, closed-questions, migration

Since list questions aren't  allowed here, e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/74912/accidental-unplanned-breakthroughs-in-physics), and recieve imediate closing, even locking, and [a meta post against it](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4838/why-should-the-list-of-breakthroughs-in-physics-be-allowed),  maybe such questions could be migrated to [Math Overflow](http://www.mathoverflow.net), where such questions are taken well?

Vote up or down if you support this or do not.

Answer (score 4):

The [breakthroughs in physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/74912/accidental-unplanned-breakthroughs-in-physics) question would *not* be on topic in Math Overflow. This is mostly because they *don't* welcome physics questions (happy as they are to take high-level mathematics questions with roots in physics), but you are also [mistaken](https://mathoverflow.net/search?page=1&tab=votes&q=closed%3a1) [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/133203/explanations-for-mathematicians-about-the-falsifiability-or-not-of-string-the) [they](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13682/which-mathematical-ideas-have-done-most-to-change-history) [generically](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18100/theorems-with-unexpected-conclusions) [welcome](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics) [list](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53122/mathematical-urban-legends) [questions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8846/proofs-without-words).

Instead of railing against the closure, why not [listen to Wouter](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4839/8563) and propose a list question policy that will allow the questions you find interesting and at the same time protects the site from ["ooooh, I have one!"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1083/do-good-math-jokes-exist) questions polluting the front page (and, specifically, addresses the concerns in [this answer](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4045/8563), [this answer](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4565/8563) and others to that same question, and [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)). You might actually find it hard!

Comment: No, they certainly do welcome physics questions. E.g. "Why does Bosonic string theory need 26 dimensions", etc.   The examples you state   are closed because they are not research level mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

This site is about physics, Math Overflow is about research-level mathematics. I can't imagine many questions that would be posted here that would be welcome on MO. Just because they allow certain list questions doesn't mean that they'll take *any* list questions.

When asking for a migration path it is pretty much required to demonstrate the need for this migration path. You should be able to point to a significant number of migrations performed by mods, or show a list of questions that should have been migrated to MO.

I'm also rather certain that MO would not welcome this migration path, they have been rather cautious about the topic of migrations towards their site. Any site can request to have a migration path shut down if it causes more trouble than it is worth. And MO has an agreement with SE that grants them more independence, so I'm pretty sure you'd have to ask them first if they want a migration path.

Comment: @DImension10AbhimanyuPS That is a strong statement. Can you back it up with, e.g., a meta.mo post where the MO community agrees to a set of physics.se list questions they would accept?