# How can I reopen the question as community wiki post?

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen

[This post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/565248/256585) is closed by a moderator. I think the reason is that it starts to have too many answers which I didn't expect. How can I reopen this question? I want to convert it to Community wiki post but I don't have any option in the edit box.

Comment: Could you clarify what reason you have to believe that the post was closed for having too many answers?

Comment: @DavidZ The post was edited at the beginning by a moderator but he didn't close it at the time.  The only change till the close was the number of answers so the conclusion.

Comment: Ah, I see. So what about the banner added to the top of the post explaining the reason for closure; did you not see that, or choose to ignore it, or so on? At any rate, you should know that moderators are different people and sometimes we will make different decisions about whether to close/edit/etc. the same question. The fact that a moderator sees a question but doesn't close it doesn't necessarily mean that it should not be closed.

Comment: @DavidZ The banner requires focus but the editing moderator and closing moderator was the same person. So I got confused.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "the banner requires focus", could you clarify?

Comment: I mean the banner says 'This question needs to be more focused. It is not currently accepting answers'.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. The banner is supposed to tell you that the question is not focused enough, which is why it was closed. Sorry, I think I'm missing something here; I just don't understand why, despite seeing that banner telling you why the question was closed, you chose to assume that it was closed for another reason.

Comment: @DavidZ As I explained, my confusion comes from two different dicisions from the moderator. He voted not to close the question at the beginning but he changed his mind later. So I concluded it was the number of questions. And the banner says something different which is another matter. So my question is why he decided to close by changing his mind concluding the question was not focused even though nothing on the question was changed from the beginning. Do you get my point?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110543/discussion-between-david-z-and-kevin).

Answer (score 4):

> I think the reason is that it starts to have too many answers which I didn't expect.

This isn't quite right. We decide whether to close a question on the merits of the question, not the answers. The problem with a question of the form *What are examples of X?* is that there are many possible answers, and so it naturally attracts many partial answers, instead of one or a few definitive answers. You can read some discussion on this type of post [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/380389) and [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4561/106502).

As for reopening it, it's hard for me to see how you could edit the question to make it more focused without completely changing what you are asking.

Comment: Related: [big-list questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4044/44126).

Comment: Meanwhile, the question has been reopened. Do five users override the site policy?..

Comment: @Ruslan If they are unaware of it or don't care, then yes. But now it is closed again.