# Why was this vector calculus question closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

I just came across [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/691010/168783), which was closed under the site's homework policy. However, I fail to see how it is related to a specific calculation or is "check-my-work-like". While it does refer to a particular sort of expression, it seems to me that it mostly focuses on its physical meaning and how it can be found in Physics.

So what is wrong with the linked question?

**Edit:** [rob](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/44126/rob) pointed out in the comments that only two close votes were homework-related, while other two requested more focus, and the last one asked for my clarity.

I think I understand the clarity vote (even though I don't personally agree with it) since the question is incredibly general, but aren't the two questions quite related to each other, hence justifying them being asked together?

Comment: Note: of its five close votes, that question got two votes for “homework-like,” the displayed reason. It also got two votes for “needs more focus” and one vote for “needs details or clarity.”

Comment: @rob Thanks for pointing it out! Still, I also don't really see how the question lacks focus to the point of needing to be closed

Comment: The question doesn't even tell us what $A$ or $B$ are supposed to be except some vector fields. I'd call that pretty unfocused - the mathematical operation here may be a bit more specific, but I don't see any fundamental difference to asking where addition occurs in physics.

Comment: I voted to reopen. It's not homework-like in any way. The question is also quite clear, so "needs details or clarity" is inappropriate. Finally although the question doesn't say what $A$ or $B$ are aside from them being some vector fields, there aren't that many vector fields in physics, and this is a specific expression.

Answer (score 10):

That question is a poor fit to the site and not specific enough to answer.

At the time of writing, the question is:

> I would like to know if this type of term is encountered anywhere in physics and mechanics?

In essence that's a list-type question and these are generally considered off-topic as there's no way to judge an answer - one example is as good as another.

> Can we attribute a physical meaning to such terms?

This is entirely dependent on what the vectors are.  You cannot attribute any special meaning to this beyond that without a context for the vectors.

Comment: "off-topic as there's no way to judge an answer - one example is as good as another": the objective of the site is provide answers to questions, sort them is only an useful feature. A question is still valid even if answers can not be sorted. Moreover, in this case, answers that refers to more common physics scenarios are better than very particular ones.

Comment: Given this, how would you judge [this similarly-themed question on a GR identity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/691433/25301)?

Comment: @KyleKanos That question seems more focused as it provides a specific equation it asks about a meaning for and the equation has a very specific context (GR).  I'm not sure it can be usefully answered, but I don't think it's crosses any lines clearly enough to be closed as unclear.

Comment: @pasabaporaqui That may be your interpretation of the site, however while I've been using SE list-type questions have always been regarded as dodgy.  The most relevant Physics Meta SE post is possibly [this one](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4044/why-exactly-are-big-list-questions-discouraged-shouldnt-the-faq-say-this-promi).  In my experience list-typoe questions that are acceptable tend to be resource requests - usually requestions for suitable books for specific study requirements.

Comment: @pasabaporaqui Questions on PSE should have a correct answer. For lists there isn't really a "correct answer", just answers that add to the list.